# DAX Measure per category

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have this DAX measure

```
Average Weeks in Warehouse = 
  CALCULATE( 
    sum('Stock-Dwellings combined'[PalletWeeksTOTAL]) / 
    sum('Stock-Dwellings combined'[FullPalletsQty])
  )
```

In table Stock=Dwellings combined I have field CustomerCode which I want to use as a slicer.

How to make measure to take work only with specific CutomerCode field not on the whole dataset?

Comment: If the above is truly a Measure, then it will auto-calculate with the filtered table (sliced by Customer Code). Update your question withh a sample of your table in [markdown format](https://tabletomarkdown.com/). Also you should use `DIVIDE( a, b )` instead of `a / b`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
Average Weeks in Warehouse for Specific Customer = 
CALCULATE( 
    DIVIDE(
        SUM('Stock-Dwellings combined'[PalletWeeksTOTAL]), 
        SUM('Stock-Dwellings combined'[FullPalletsQty]),
        BLANK() 
    ),
    FILTER(
        'Stock-Dwellings combined',
        'Stock-Dwellings combined'[CustomerCode] = "yourCustomerCode"
    )
)
```